# How to set the default/prefilled value of a input element in mat-form-field on load?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

So I want to implement an html element such that the default data(the variable 'preselectedValue') should be already be entered/prefilled into the input field when the component loads and the user should be able to directly edit the search string.

autocomplete-display-example.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
  <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

autocomplete-display-example.ts

```
export class AutocompleteDisplayExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl<string | User>('');
  options: User[] = [{name: 'Mary'}, {name: 'Shelley'}, {name: 'Igor'}];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;
  preselectedValue = "John";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => {
        const name = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.name;
        return name ? this._filter(name as string) : this.options.slice();
      }),
    );

  }

  displayFn(user: User): string {
    return user && user.name ? user.name : '';
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your `mat-option` is of type `User`. So you have to pass it a preselected value of that type. The code in your question does not show the definition of the User class but you could try something like this:

```
preselectedValue = {name: 'John} as User;

ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl.value = preselectedValue;
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => {
        const name = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.name;
        return name ? this._filter(name as string) : this.options.slice();
      }),
    );
  }
```